# How to find all possible minimal edge covers over $K_6$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How to find all possible minimal edge covers over $K_6$?
$K_6$-complete graph of $6$ vertices.
On working out I found out that there would be [these](https://photos.app.goo.gl/YJm6jPg6yBgsSZxk8) many cases ..

Can somebody tell me if this what I have done is right?
Or are there any more cases?

Comment: What about a conected to b,c,d and e-f that is 4 edges.

Comment: What about a claw ($K_{1,3}$) + $K_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about $a$ conected to $b,c,d$ and $e-f$ that is $4$ edges.

So you have ${6\choose 2}\cdot {4\choose 1}$ more minimal $4$-edges cover.

Comment: That is $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}$ more.

Comment: Okay thank you for correcting...

Answer (score 0):

[OEIS A053530](https://oeis.org/A053530) provides an exponential generating function
$$\exp(-x - x^2/2 + x\exp(x)),$$ and the count for $n=6$ is 171, which confirms that your 111 plus the missing 60 cover all cases.

Comment: Thank you for the expression and link